# Git branching for django production site

Tags: django, git

I have a production website running django. Site is pretty large. I have initialted git on the main_project. So my production site is master branch. Okay. Now if I need to fix something I have created a develop branch. I switch to develop branch. edit the code and merge with master. My question is when I switch to develop branch right there, does it affect my production site, like django or mod_wsgi will see my develop branch or master branch? I am just starting to use branches in GIT.

But in truth when I need to edit something I plan to use git clone and push from my pc.

Comment: Yea , If you branch on the server , you branch on the server...   it should affect the site yes.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when I switch to develop branch right there, does it affect my production site, like `django` or `mod_wsgi` will see my develop branch or master branch?

Yes, because it affects the working tree (the directory structure monitored by `django` or `mod_wsgi`).

A better solution would be to clone it locally (on the server, or ideally on another machine), and have a second 'staging' site where you can test your fix.
One the fix is tested there, you can push to your first and current repo, in order to have it live.